# convert all column from "Nonetype" to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I am writing/saving the csv file column data are saving in **NoneType**

Individually I am changing them to numeric type using below command

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'])
```

Its fine when there are few columns but in large data set converting individual column is a big task
I am doing this because I have to plot the line graph using column data, bcz of NoneType not able to plot graph
I want to save the data in their default data type like **float data save into float type and integer data save into int type**

Comment: Best would be to provide an explicit minimal example of data and the matching expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have columns that are non-numeric, you can try this

```
for c in df.columns:
    try:
        df[c]=pd.to_numeric(df[c])
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Hope it will solve your problem :

`df = pd.to_numeric(df)`

Comment: df_new = df.to_csv(r'D:\data_ana\file_radar.csv')

df = pd.to_numeric(df_new) 

df.plot(x="Age", y="Velocity",
        kind="line", figsize=(10, 10))
 
# display plot
mp.show()

Error - 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'plot'

Comment: I think you need to focus on the plot function you used. Try something like this,
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
`plt.plot(df)`

You can also refer here. [link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html)

Comment: same error after using  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.plot(df)